# On apple iphone what event is captured on tap of a notification?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, events, onpaste

I have a React application. I am testing on apple mobile phone. My problem is that when I receive a SMS, I get the number as suggestion above keyboard. When I tap on it, I need that number to be filled on an OTP input box. So what is the event triggered on tap?

onPaste and onDrop event does not work for on tap.

Answer (score 0):

On all push notification tap this method of appDelegate class called :

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,didReceiveresponse: UNNotificationResponse,withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) { 

}
```